# Executing JavaScript in an Ajax Response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax form process. But I do this process when I click a function. When I click it opens a PHP Form in a Jquery Dialog. But When I process the form the POST VARs are NULL.

This is the code:

The main file with the function to request the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Aircrafts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../lib/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../lib/css/flick/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="../../../lib/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../lib/js/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../lib/js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../lib/js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../lib/js/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../lib/js/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../lib/js/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../lib/js/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../lib/js/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../lib/js/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>


    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#loadingdialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 300,
            height: 65
        });

        $("#loadingdialog").dialog('widget').find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
        $("#loadingdialog").dialog('widget').find(".ui-resizable-se").hide();

        $( "#editaircraftdialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 425
        });

        $("#editaircraftdialog").dialog('widget').find(".ui-resizable-se").hide();                   
    });

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
            else
                {
                ajax=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }


     function edit(str) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "./edit_aircraft.php?icao="+str,
                context: document.body,
                success: function(responseText) {
                    $("#editaircraftdialog").html(responseText);
                    $("#editaircraftdialog").find("script").each(function(i) {
                        eval($(this).text());
                    });
                    $("#editaircraftdialog").dialog('open');
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="result"></div></br>

    <div id="loadingdialog"><center><p><img src="../../../lib/images/loading.gif"></center></p></div>

    <div id="editaircraftdialog"></div>


 <?php
    require_once('../../config.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM aircrafts ORDER BY ICAO ASC LIMIT";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result)
{
die (mysql_error());
}

echo "<table border='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr><th class=tabletitles>ICAO</th><th class=tabletitles>Edit</th></tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    if($i++%2==0){
       $color="#FFFFFF";
    }else{
       $color="#CCCCCC";
    }

    ?>

    <tr bgcolor='<?php echo $color; ?>' onmouseover="this.style.background='#ABFB04';" onmouseout="this.style.background='<?php echo $color; ?>';">
    <?php

echo "<td class=tablelist>";

echo $row["ICAO"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';


echo "<img src=\"../../../lib/images/edit.png\" onclick=\"edit('".$row["ICAO"]."')\"></td><td class=tablelist>";

}

echo "</table>";
mysql_close();
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The file with the AJAX form process and the PHP form:

```
<?php
require_once ('../../config.php');
$icao = $_GET["icao"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM aircrafts WHERE ICAO = '$icao'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result)
{
die (mysql_error());
}

?>
<form action="javascript:editForm();" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> 
<?php
echo '<table border="0">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

echo '<tr><td class="forms">ICAO:</td><td><input type="text" id="icao" name="icao" size="30" value=';
echo $row["ICAO"] . "></td></tr>";

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="30" value=';
echo $row["Name"] . "></td></tr>";

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Weight Empty:</td><td><input type="text" id="weightempty" name="weightempty" size="30" value=';
echo $row["WeightEmpty"] . "></td></tr>";

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Weight Full:</td><td><input type="text" id="weightfull" name="weightfull" size="30" value=';
echo $row["WeightFull"] . "></td></tr>";

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Cargo Full:</td><td><input type="text" id="cargofull" name="cargofull" size="30" value=';
echo $row["CargoFull"] . "></td></tr>";

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Cruise Speed:</td><td><input type="text" id="cruisespeed" name="cruisespeed" size="30" value=';
echo $row["CruiseSpeed"] . "></td></tr>";

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Range:</td><td><input type="text" id="range" name="range" size="30" value=';
echo $row["Range"] . "></td></tr>";

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Price:</td><td><input type="text" id="price" name="price" size="30" value=';
echo $row["Price"] . "></td></tr>";

if($row["FirstClassSeats"] != NULL && $row["FirstClassSeats"] != 0){
echo '<tr><td class="forms">First Class Seats:</td><td><input type="text" id="firstclassseats" name="firstclassseats" size="30" value=';
echo $row["FirstClassSeats"] . "></td></tr>";}

if($row["BusinessClassSeats"] != NULL && $row["BusinessClassSeats"] != 0){
echo '<tr><td class="forms">Business Class Seats:</td><td><input type="text" id="businessclassseats" name="businessclassseats" size="30" value=';
echo $row["BusinessClassSeats"] . "></td></tr>";}

if($row["EconomyClassSeats"] != NULL && $row["EconomyClassSeats"] != 0){
echo '<tr><td class="forms">Economy Class Seats:</td><td><input type="text" id="economyclassseats" name="economyclassseats" size="30" value=';
echo $row["EconomyClassSeats"] . "></td></tr>";}

echo '<tr><td><input id="editaircraft" type="submit" value="Edit Aircraft"></td></tr>';

}
echo "</table>";
?>

</form>
<script>

    $(function() {
        $("#editaircraft")
            .button()
            .click(function editForm() {
        });
    });

function editForm(){

            var icao = document.getElementById('icao').value;
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var weightempty = document.getElementById('weightempty').value;
            var weightfull = document.getElementById('weightfull').value;
            var cargofull = document.getElementById('cargofull').value;
            var cruisespeed = document.getElementById('cruisespeed').value;
            var range = document.getElementById('range').value;
            var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
            var firstclassseats = document.getElementById('firstclassseats').value;
            var businessclassseats = document.getElementById('businessclassseats').value;
            var economyclassseats = document.getElementById('economyclassseats').value;
            ajax.open("POST","edit_aircraft_process.php",true);
            ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(ajax.readyState==4)
                {
                refreshTable(function(){$("#loadingdialog").dialog('close');});

                refreshTable(function(){$("#result").fadeIn(); document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=ajax.responseText;});
                setTimeout(function() { $("#result").fadeOut() }, 5000);
                }
            }
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajax.send("icao="+icao+"&name="+name+"&weightempty="+weightempty+"&weightfull="+weightfull+"&cargofull="+cargofull+"&cruisespeed="+cruisespeed+"&range="+range+"&price="+price+"&firstclassseats="+firstclassseats+"&businessclassseats="+businessclassseats+"&economyclassseats="+economyclassseats);
        $("#editaircraftdialog").dialog('close');
        $("#loadingdialog").dialog('open');
        }
</script>
```

When I execute the editForm, works and put the result of the process in the `<div id="result">` fine. But, the vars that send to edit in the database (for example icao) are NULL and it edit nothing.

I think the error is because after ajax request it can´t do the `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure what the exact problem is but on quickly checking your code here's 2 things:

1. You are not properly closing the input tags eg:

   ```
    echo '<tr><td class="forms">ICAO:</td><td><input type="text" id="icao" name="icao" size="30" value=';
   echo $row["ICAO"] . "/></td></tr>";// <--- notice the added forward slash to close the input
   ```
2. you are not surrounding the `value` attribute with `""`:

   ```
    echo '<tr><td class="forms">ICAO:</td><td><input type="text" id="icao" name="icao" size="30" value="'; //<-- open here
   echo $row["ICAO"] . '"/></td></tr>'; //<--- notice the closing "
   ```

Comment: Can you put the code, without the errors? I don´t know How can I close it and surrounding the value ok.

Comment: The code above is with the errors fixed. Use the second one and both are fixed

Comment: Make sure you do the same to the other inputs though!

Comment: OK, I fix it. But it ins´t the problem! I don´t know why the document.getElementById don´t found!

Comment: Do you have a live demo to look at? If not try `console.log(icao)` as soon as you create the var in editForm() if that is showing fine then keep moving console.log() down until you find the error!

Comment: the console result is: [input#icao, input#icao, item: function, namedItem: function]
undefined

Comment: seen as you are using jquery anyway, try `var icao = $("#icao").val();`

Answer (score 0):

In XML, fragment identifiers are of type ID, and there can only be a single attribute of type ID per element. Therefore, in XHTML 1.0 the id attribute is defined to be of type ID. In order to ensure that XHTML 1.0 documents are well-structured XML documents.

in this case you are Loop the data into same input id. Change your code into this :

```
var i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

echo '<tr><td class="forms">ICAO:</td><td><input type="text" id="icao_' . i . '" name="icao" size="30" value="';
echo $row["ICAO"] . '"></td></tr>"';

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="name_' . i . '" name="name" size="30" value="';
echo $row["Name"] . '"></td></tr>"';

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Weight Empty:</td><td><input type="text" id="weightempty_' . i . '" name="weightempty" size="30" value="';
echo $row["WeightEmpty"] . '"></td></tr>"';

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Weight Full:</td><td><input type="text" id="weightfull_' . i . '" name="weightfull" size="30" value="';
echo $row["WeightFull"] . '"></td></tr>"';

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Cargo Full:</td><td><input type="text" id="cargofull_' . i . '" name="cargofull" size="30" value="';
echo $row["CargoFull"] . '"></td></tr>"';

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Cruise Speed:</td><td><input type="text" id="cruisespeed_' . i . '" name="cruisespeed" size="30" value="';
echo $row["CruiseSpeed"] . '"></td></tr>"';

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Range:</td><td><input type="text" id="range_' . i . '" name="range" size="30" value="';
echo $row["Range"] . '"></td></tr>"';

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Price:</td><td><input type="text" id="price_' . i . '" name="price" size="30" value="';
echo $row["Price"] . '"></td></tr>"';

if($row["FirstClassSeats"] != NULL && $row["FirstClassSeats"] != 0){
echo '<tr><td class="forms">First Class Seats:</td><td><input type="text" id="firstclassseats_' . i . '" name="firstclassseats" size="30" value="';
echo $row["FirstClassSeats"] . '"></td></tr>"';}

if($row["BusinessClassSeats"] != NULL && $row["BusinessClassSeats"] != 0){
echo '<tr><td class="forms">Business Class Seats:</td><td><input type="text" id="businessclassseats_' . i . '" name="businessclassseats" size="30" value="';
echo $row["BusinessClassSeats"] . '"></td></tr>"';}

if($row["EconomyClassSeats"] != NULL && $row["EconomyClassSeats"] != 0){
echo '<tr><td class="forms">Economy Class Seats:</td><td><input type="text" id="economyclassseats_' . i . '" name="economyclassseats" size="30" value="';
echo $row["EconomyClassSeats"] . '"></td></tr>"';}

echo '<tr><td><input id="editaircraft_' . i . '" type="submit" value="Edit Aircraft"></td></tr>';
i++;
}
```

Then you can send the data by using jquery serialize

Change this :

```
ajax.send("icao="+icao+"&name="+name+"&weightempty="+weightempty+"&weightfull="+weightfull+"&cargofull="+cargofull+"&cruisespeed="+cruisespeed+"&range="+range+"&price="+price+"&firstclassseats="+firstclassseats+"&businessclassseats="+businessclassseats+"&economyclassseats="+economyclassseats);
```

into this:

```
ajax.send($("form").serialize());
```

Comment: The first code isn´t OK. You are putting a Javascript var in php. I need to chenge de var to PHP? I need to change the vars  document.getElementById?

Comment: i'm sorry i forget, just change var i into PHP variable $i